# How to make my program let the user enter text in JtextField before running the rest of the code? (Java 8)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Here is the code:

```
public void stage() {
    textarea1.setText("You are walking home from a long journey to your castle when you witness a huge explosion!");
    textarea1.setText(textarea1.getText() + "\n" + "What do you do?:\n(1)Run into the burning castle\n(2)Attend to the wounded\n(3)Look for the arsonist.");
    // need to force user to input text here
    if (Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText()) == 1) {
        textarea1.setText(textarea1.getText() + "\n" +"You attempt to run into the castle to save the inhabitants but the smoke and heat are too much. You exit the castle.");
        textarea1.setText(textarea1.getText() + "\n" + "What do you do?:\n(1)Attend to the wounded\n(1)Look for the arsonist.");
        if (Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText()) == 1) {
            stage2();
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText()) == 2) {
            stage3();
        } else {
            textarea1.setText(textarea1.getText() + "\n" +"Please type the number before the choice you would like and press ENTER");
            stage1();
        }
    }
    if (Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText()) == 2) {
        stage2();
    }
    if (Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText()) == 3) {
        stage3();
    } else {
        textarea1.setText(textarea1.getText() + "\n" +"Please type the number before the choice you would like and press ENTER");
        stage1();
    }
}
```

Basically I'm writing a game, and at the start of this method the user has a few choices. The user has to enter his choice (1, 2, or 3) in a `JTextField` and the program goes to different methods based on the input using a series of if/else statements. However the program doesn't allow the user time to input a choice in the `JTextField` before running the if/else statements therefore it always goes to else and creates an infinite loop. If I was writing in C++ I know I could use a system(pause) and if I wasn't using Swing in Java I could use a scanner class. How can I force my program to allow time for the user to input an integer in the `JTextField`? Thanks for the help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: Look up and use the MVC (model-view-control) pattern, since this is a situation where it would be very useful. For your situation, you would base your program's responses on the current state of its model. Since your program is a event-driven GUI, you would not need pauses or sleeps, but rather changes to the state of the model and the view (which displays the state of the model for the user) changing when the model changes. You would also avoid hard-coding data in your view class (your gui), and instead let the data portion, including the text displayed be separate, and likely in a text file.

Answer (score 2):

You could just call the if-statements **after** 'ENTER' was pressed.

```
myComponent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //insert if-statements
    }
}); 
// do this with all your textfields
```

Comment: You should maybe suggest him to work with ActionListeners... :)

Comment: *"(with an ActionListener or KeyListener)"*  Use an `ActionListener` for a `JTextField`.  It is simpler.  The OP might also consider `JRadioButton` components in a `ButtonGroup`, a `JSpinner` or a `JComboBox` for a 'multi-choice answer'..  (Easier than parsing an integer from a text field, and easier for the end user to input.)

Comment: *"Easier way is to add a JButton to your frame and add an ActionListener.."*  Unnecessary.  See [`JTextField.addActionListener(ActionListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-).  It will fire when the user presses the `Enter` key.

Comment: You're welcome.  +1 for the answer and happy 'triple figure rep.'.  :)

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the help @LuxxMiner.

Answer (score 1):

I hereby suggest another solution, providing you a little bit advanced functionality. Please also consider @LuxxMiner's answer.

**This solution uses a combobox, you can adapt it for a textfield if you are 'forced' to**

```
public class Main extends Application {

  @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("LittleGame");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new AnchorPane() {
      {
        getChildren().add(new ComboBox<String>() {
          {
            getItems().addAll("Run", "Fight", "Cry!");
            setValue("Choose your style");
            valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
              switch (newValue) {
              case "Run":
                System.out.println("You chose to run, fool!");
                //Goto stage run
                break;
              case "Fight":
                System.out.println("You chose to fight!");
                //Goto stage fight
                break;
              case "Cry!":
                System.out.println("You chose to cry!");
                //Goto stage cry
                break;
              default:
                System.out.println("*This fight style is not available!*");
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

This code uses anonymous classes to be as short as possible, you should use a more structured approach when really using this :)

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of doing it this way, it is nice to know there are many solutions to one problem in programming.